# Bring Menu to front

Tags: html, css

Could you tell me how to bring menu's black background in front of the body text on the image below.

Here is JSFiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/johnking/j58cubux/6/

When you scroll down, the menu is not properly visible

```
<body>
<div class="uppersection">
<div class="menu" id="home">
    <ul>

        <li>
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>


        <li class="drop">
        <a href="google.ca">About</a>
            <ul class="haha">
                <li><a href="www.google.ca">Who am I?</li></a>
                <li><a href="www.google.ca">Accomplishments</li></a>
                <li><a href="www.google.ca">Academic Work</li></a>
                <li><a href="www.google.ca">Future Plans</li></a>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="google.ca">Resume</a>
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="google.ca">Portfolio</a>       
        </li>

        <li>
        <a href="google.ca">Contact</a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
<div class=textupper>Hello, I am John <br><br>Welcome To My Website!<br>    <br>Feel Free To Navigate Around</div>
</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Hi</body>
```

How can I fix the problem using css?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add background for `a` too in case if parent `li` is hovered:

```
.menu ul li:hover a {
    background-color: #00AFF0;
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/j58cubux/7/

Or better solution is to set `a` background color to `transparent` by default:

```
.menu ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Segoe UI Local;
    background-color: transparent; /* make it transparent */
}
```

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/j58cubux/8/

Answer (score 0):

Your menu `a` has a black background that is showing up above the blue background of the `li`.

Just remove that black background (remove this line):

```
background-color: black;
```

from your `.menu ul li a` definition.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j58cubux/10/

Answer (score 0):

use the property "z-index: 1000;" in ".menu". So fix the menu at the top regardless of the scrolling content.

```
.menu {
   background-color: black;
   min-height: 77px;
   width: 100%;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
}
```

See you later!

Comment: z-index: 1000; solved the problem, thank you so much